# ASP.NET design view not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, vb.net

I'm working on someone project in the job but he is not here any more.

I'm going to edit the website using VS 2010

The problem is when I open the code, the design view is not working but what I'm not understanding that when I run it in the web browser the design is there!

How can I fix this problem to see the design in VS 2010

[image]

Comment: <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=p3eo5" target="_blank"><img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/p3eo5.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a> this is a picture

Comment: many times that designer gets break when you use dynamic html elements using master page and external css or images, and i recommend you to use firebug to debug the scripts and css.

Comment: firebug is for browser and i want to see the design in visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `master page` and please check all your `css` files and `images` are in the right folder and check they are referred correctly in your `<head>` section of your master page.